# Server to Server authentication for client - Single threaded

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, netty

I am creating a login-server for my client to server application.

Basically there are 5 servers, and all of these servers are connected to one login-server.

The client can connect to any of these 5 servers, but it needs to authenticate with username and a password. Authentication should be done in the login server, and the login server should return an answer to the actual server that should return the answer to the client.

So its like that:

Client -> Server -> Login-server -> Server -> Client (response code)

Now, I am using Netty and it's NIO, it's not thread-per-client. Now, to authenticate with NIO, we must wait for a response to arrive from the login-server, and that can take a while and delay other clients that want to login, actually you can't just wait for an answer with NIO like that. So I thought of an idea on how can I make it work. My idea was run the request on a different thread and have an event with `onResponse(String key, int responseCode)` method and then put the client's channel in a map with a generated key, so that way we can know who the response belongs to. So when we authenticate, we send the key, and user's data.

But I feel that this is a bad way and there is a more efficient method to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK netty supports blocking NIO with a thread per connection.  Note the *default* behaviour of NIO is blocking operations and until recently only Socket supported non-blocking operations as an option.

Comment: In multi server environment it will be broken when use map to keep channels.

Comment: Just a suggestion, since you asked for better ways to do this - if you're using Java you may want to look into websockets i.e. html 5 + http(s). Then you get a thread per client model to work with, authentication with encryption is transparent to your application, and you get all the capabilities of NIO with no end client to deploy.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have full control of all system:

Assign an ID for each client connection in the server. Then when you need to authenticate the user, include this connection ID in the request from the server to the login server and return without waiting for the reply from the login server.

Some time in the future your server will receive login response from the login server. If the login response contains the client connection ID - use that ID to find a connection from a server to a client and relay that reply back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it.

**Setup**

Create a Channel wrapper class, so that you can identify which channel belongs to which client.

```
public class CustomChannel implements Channel {

    private final Channel channel;
    private final String clientId;

    ...
}
```

Create a custom ChannelMatcher for matching client's channel:

```
public class CustomChannelMatcher implements ChannelMatcher {
    private final String clientId;

    public CustomChannelMatcher(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean matches(Channel channel) {
        if (channel instanceof CustomChannel) {
            return clientId.equals(((CustomChannel) channel).getClientId());
        }
        return false;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Handling Request**

In your client handler, use ChannelGroup to keep track of your clients' channels.

```
ChannelGroup channelGroup = new DefaultChannelGroup(GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);

...

channelGroup.add(new CustomChannel(ctx.channel(), clientId));

// send request to another server without blocking
```

**Handling Response**

In your server handler, use your CustomChannelMatcher to match the client's channel.

```
// when the server responds sometimes later

channelGroup.writeAndFlush(responseMessage, 
    new CustomChannelMatcher(clientId));
```

The code above will find a matching client's channel and write the message to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are worried to block an NIO worker thread, but you spin another thread to perform the login. You just used one more thread anyway. So define more threads in your server for http(s) and be done with it. Unless you expect over 100 concurrent logins, there is no issue here.

NIO is way overrated; the OS is great at scheduling threads and context switching, much better than you would in java doing backflips with asyn apis. Waiting threads do not consume CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you were on Netty. I just need to say something about servlet api though (in case you can use it):

FYI, this is problem addressed with the servlet api 3.0+ which allows you to perform exactly that work in an AsynContext. Not kidding, read up on the servlet 3.0, preferably javaone youtube presentations and tutorials, even the PDF specification is better than the javadoc.

And if you even want to perform NIO on the servletinputstream/servletoutputstream, you can do so (although a bit involved) with servlet api 3.1. The javaone presentation (2014 I think) is great.